# How to format a column in DataGridView with C#

Tags: c#, binding, datagridview, bindingsource

I used BindingSource to connect my DataGridView with a Microsoft Access DB.

The field in the DB is a Time is a Long Time (Input Mask is 99:00 >LL;0;_)

The DataGridView shows

> 12/30/1899 9:56 AM

The time is correct but the DataGridView is showing the 12/30/1899

Please help!

Comment: This is a WinForm app and not an ASP page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to set the `DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t"`

you can display only the time via the properties window for your `datagridview', look for the Columns option.  Then select your column that you want to change > DefaultCellStyle > Format >  Date Time > time option.

or in code:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["yourColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t";
```

here is some info on formatting data in a datagridview

[How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx)

[DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle.aspx)

Comment: t is the format used for time only, I have added code to format the column.